# How can I fix the background of wikipedia pages as displayed in Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

See image here:

[image: Example]

The background of all wikipedia pages is always blue in Chrome.  I am not sure how to fix this, I have tried the obvious stuff like closing and re-opening Chrome and deleting my cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this before and it was to do with the zoom level that was set for wikipedia. More info [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113711). Might not be the same issue for you but worked for me.

Comment: Thank you!  When I zoomed in to 100% zoom, this issue went away.